# Picking up data from excel

Tags: xml

I have a list of data in excel which contain almost 4500 columns and 15000 rows,

I want a macro which will search a word of my choice in excel and along with the cell which contains that word  that word it will copy cell adjacent (left as well as right) to that in other excel sheet

For example if I search a word "ABC" in my data the macro should pick up that cell which contains "ABC" and cells which are adjacent (left as well as right) in other excel sheet and it should do this for all the cells which contains "ABC".

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I probably understood it wrong but how about ctrl + f

Comment: i want to copy that data in other excel along with the cell which are next to that (Left and Right)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is Ctrl H on windows

Comment: i want to copy that data in other excel along with the cell which are next to that (Left and Right)